Issues with Signal Restoration using TensorFlow STFT and Inverse STFT
I have implemented STFT (Short-Time Fourier Transform) and inverse STFT in both TensorFlow and PyTorch. While the PyTorch version successfully restores the original signal, the TensorFlow version does not.
Here are my implementations for tensorflow:
def spectro(
        signal: tf.Tensor, n_fft: int = 4096, hop_length: int = None
    ) -> tf.Tensor:

        if hop_length is None:
            hop_length = n_fft // 4

        assert hop_length == n_fft // 4, "hop_length should be n_fft // 4"
        frames = int(math.ceil(signal.shape[-1] / hop_length))

        pad_left = (hop_length // 2 * 3) 
        pad_right = pad_left + frames * hop_length - signal.shape[-1]
        pad_second = (n_fft // 2) 

        # shape (batch, channel, signal) -> (batch, channel, signal + pad_left + pad_right)
        padded_signal = STFTUtils.pad_1d(signal, (pad_left, pad_right), "REFLECT")
        padded_signal = STFTUtils.pad_1d(padded_signal, (pad_second, pad_second), "REFLECT")  
    
        window_fn = tf.signal.hann_window
        *other, length = padded_signal.shape
        padded_signal = tf.reshape(padded_signal,[-1,length])
    
        stfts = tf.signal.stft(
            padded_signal,
            frame_length=n_fft,
            frame_step=hop_length,
            fft_length=n_fft,
            window_fn=window_fn,
        )  # shape (batch, channel, fft_bins, fft_length // 2 + 1)
        _,frames_sec, frequency = stfts.shape
        stfts = stfts[..., : , :-1]
        stfts = stfts[..., 2 : 2 + frames, : ]
        return stfts  # shape (batch, channel, fft_bins - 4, fft_length // 2)


def inverse_spectro(spectrograms, hop_length=None, signal_length=None) -> tf.Tensor:
        spectrograms = tf.pad(spectrograms, [[0, 0], [0, 0], [2,2], [0,1]])
        *other_dims, num_freqs = spectrograms.shape
        n_fft = 2 * num_freqs - 2

        if hop_length is None:
            hop_length = n_fft // 4
        window_fn = tf.signal.hann_window
        signal = tf.signal.inverse_stft(
            spectrograms,
            frame_length=n_fft,
            frame_step=hop_length,
            fft_length=n_fft,
            window_fn=window_fn
        )  # shape (batch, channel, signal_length + padding)
        padding = (hop_length // 2 * 3) + (n_fft // 2)  # Amount of padding that was applied

        signal = signal[..., padding : signal_length + padding]

        return signal  # shape (batch, channel, signal_length)

Here are my implementations for torch:
def spectro(x, n_fft=512, hop_length=None, pad=0):
    *other, length = x.shape
    x = x.reshape(-1, length)
    is_mps = x.device.type == 'mps'
    if is_mps:
        x = x.cpu()
    import torch
    #print("before stft", x, x.shape, torch.sum(torch.square(x)))
    z = th.stft(x,
                n_fft * (1 + pad),
                hop_length or n_fft // 4,
                window=th.hann_window(n_fft).to(x),
                win_length=n_fft,
                normalized=False,
                center=True,
                return_complex=True,
                pad_mode='reflect')
    
    _, freqs, frame = z.shape
    return z.view(*other, freqs, frame)


def ispectro(z, hop_length=None, length=None, pad=0):
    *other, freqs, frames = z.shape
    n_fft = 2 * freqs - 2
    z = z.view(-1, freqs, frames)
    win_length = n_fft // (1 + pad)
    is_mps = z.device.type == 'mps'
    if is_mps:
        z = z.cpu()
    x = th.istft(z,
                 n_fft,
                 hop_length,
                 window=th.hann_window(win_length).to(z.real),
                 win_length=win_length,
                 normalized=False,
                 length=length,
                 center=True)
    _, length = x.shape
    return x.view(*other, length)

In the PyTorch code, I can restore the original signal without issues. However, the TensorFlow version does not restore the original signal properly. What could be the probable issues in my TensorFlow implementation?
Thank you for your help!

what is STFTUtils? Please share full reproducible code. Better to use colab.

Thanks for your comment. I have solved the issue. I have found that I have to send the window function in a different way in istft.
Like this: window_fn=tf.signal.inverse_stft_window_fn(frame_step)
After incorporating the window function in the following way I was able to reconstruct the original signal through istft in tensorflow code.
